# How to add extra field to picture chooser dialog?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera

In my android app I allow user to select picture from gallery or other sources using the following code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(
    intent, "Select Picture"), PICTURE_CHOOSER);
```

When user clicks on a button, a dialog appears where user can choose application to load image (f.e., file manager or gallery). Can I add an additional button to that dialog so the user will be able to capture image from camera?

Comment: you mean that the additional button should open up a camera right?

Comment: @ParthDoshi yes. However, my trouble is not opening a camera but actually adding new button to the dialog.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can add a Button to the default Intent that Android provides for selecting a picture.

However, what you can do is create a **Custom Dialog** that consists of two buttons. One to perform the  Select picture action and the other the camera.

Here is a [tutorial](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-display-custom-dialog-your-android-application) for implementing CustomDialog in Android.

So by adding the two buttons and then associating each with the action you need to do, you can develop your application. Hope it helps!